# Styling text in a SearchBar / TextField iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an iOS app using swift. I have a SearchBar/Textview (i've tried with both) and want to split each search term a user types in, into a bubble similar to pinterest where the user can later press the cross to remove certain ones.

How do I start with this? I can only seem to change the background of the whole TextField instead of just for each word.

Here's a sample of what I am trying to achieve.

[Here's a sample of what I am trying to achieve http://www.standingdog.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/pinterest-guided-search-screen-shot.jpg](http://www.standingdog.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/pinterest-guided-search-screen-shot.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a formatted text. What they are doing is different. When a space/enter is typed in (and you can detect that by the `UITextField` delegate), you take the currently written text and create a view from it.

The structure of that view will be similar to the following:

```
+ view
   + label with the text
   + x (remove) button
```

You will then add this view to a container view. The purpose of this view is to keep the search term views in a list.

You can then assign this container view to `[UITextField leftView]`.

Of course, then you have to handle removal, backspace etc.

Comment: Ah, I never thought of it like that. Thanks I give it a try.